# BQ24618 not charging (LiPo Battery managment IC)

Tags: battery-charging, lipo, texas-instruments

I have been trying to build a LiPo charger based on the IC BQ24618 (Texas Instruments). I already have the PCB design based on the datasheet's schematich and I double checked all the layout recommendations. Nevertheless, the circuit is not working properly.

The specific problem is that the charging MOSFETs seems to fail (somehow). I have the suspicion that they get triggered simultaneously when plugging in the battery. I tried to prevent this with a series RC snubber network but they still failing.

does anyone have experience with this kind of ICs?

**EDIT n°1:**
I think I made it work. For some reason, the previous high-side MOSFET was bad. So I tried new MOSFETs and I added a slightly bigger gate resistor. This time they managed to charge the battery! but I am not completely sure about the triggering of the gates (regardless the IC **did** charge the battery):
[image: High and low side MOSFET of the Buck Converter]
The yellow curve is the High-side MOSFET's gate voltage. Bootstrap make it 6V above the source voltage, this works great. But the blue curve is the low-side MOSFET's gate voltage. The ugly shape of low-side gate right after the triggering is due to some poor response of my oscilloscope's channel 2 (it would look much better if I measure that gate with channel 1 only) My question now is: Why low-side gate is only triggered for a short while and not along all the low-state of the high-side MOSFET?

I expected a push-pull alternating triggering.

Vin voltage is 18,4V and battery voltage is around 11,8V (not fully charged). Charging current is set to be 1,2Amps.

Best Regards

Comment: Post oscilloscope captures!

Comment: Post the layout. Lots of SMPS problems are due to layout. Also look at switching waveform. Bad layout will show up as erratic duty cycle.

Comment: This is not a new part. You can assume the part itself works. So you just have to figure out what you did wrong. Since you already say that you didn't make any mistakes, you have kind of left us with nowhere to go to help you. You might try putting a 100uF aluminum electrolytic cap on the input power supply. If the problem really is inrush overshoot, that should damp it out. You may want to read Linear app note AN88. http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an88f.pdf